# How to make a new paragraph with formula?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

```
\noindent $(1)$ \textit{If $\theta \in [\frac{1}{\alpha},\infty]$, we have}

\begin{flalign} 

\int_0^{\tau} t^{-\theta} dS_t = \infty \ \forall \tau >0, \textit{a.s.}  && \tag{1.1}

\end{flalign}
```

Why I don't get a paragraph before an integral like here:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. In this case, once I complete the above code to be a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301), (adding `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{amsmath}`) it seems to work fine.

Comment: If you issue is with the indentation of the math, that is what `flalign` is supposed to do, perhaps you desire `align` environment instead.

Comment: (1) Remove the blank lines from within the `flalign` environment; (2) You can insert `\hspace*{\parindent}` at the start to simulate a paragraph indentation.

Answer (score 1):

If I have not misunderstood you would like the integral that you have put as an image to be all in the left side. My humble proposal (seeing also the comments) is to use this simple MWE where I have added `fourier` package to have about the same typography as in the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{If $\ \theta \in [\frac{1}{\alpha},\infty)$, we have}
\begin{flalign}
    \int_0^T t^{-\theta}\mathrm{d}S_t=\infty, \quad \forall \,T>0, \quad \textit{a.s.}&&
\end{flalign}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```